# Yii: How to add inline style to select option item?

Tags: php, yii2

I have select HTML tag generated by this code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'something')->dropDownList(Class::method(), 
  ['prompt' => Yii::t('app', '--- Choose ---')]) ?>
```

I would need to add an HTML attribute (e.g. inline style) to each option tag.

Can you give me a hint, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use options

```
  <?= $form->field($model, 'something')->dropDownList(Class::method(), 
   ['prompt' => Yii::t('app', '--- Choose ---'), 
     'options' => ['value1' => ['style' => 'color:red;'],]]) ?>
```